# How to link an item in Diablo 3 on Console (Xbox One)

Tags: diablo-iii-console

On PC I seem to remember that I could link an item in chat so that my friends in the same session can see what I just got. I mean, besides being able to kill stuff faster, what point is there for getting new shiny loot if I cannot brag about it...

So, on Console, and from my point of view, Xbox One, is this possible, besides opening up a trade and placing it in there, or dropping it on the ground?

I know I can inspect my friends characters to see what they have, so I know that there are ways to see the items, but linking, is this possible? Just "See what I just got"?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this question remains unanswered for so long. The answer is no. In the PC version, the game prints the item link in a text chat box. There is no such text chat box in the console version of the game, as such, any functionality associated with the text chat box isn't present (such as callouts for when a player engages with an Elite monster).

The only way to view items' stats is through the inventory screen, or the party screen.